# Determining Christoffel Symbols and Curvature Tensors for a Flat Sphere using SymPy.Diffgeom

Tags: python, sympy

Using [SymPy.Diffgeom library](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/diffgeom.html), I am trying to determine the Christoffel symbols for a given metric tensor. I am having some issues with determining the Christoffel symbols for a flat sphere (r = constant, theta, phi). The curve element is defined as following :

```
flat_metric = r**2*sin(theta)**2*TensorProduct(dphi, dphi) + r**2*TensorProduct(dtheta, dtheta)
```

The metric tensor is given as

```
flat_g = Matrix([[r**2,0],[0,r**2*sin(theta)**2]]).
```

In 3-dimensions for coordinates (r, theta, phi), this translates to

```
g = Matrix([[0,0,0],[0,r**2,0],[0,0,r**2*sin(theta)**2]]).
```

Supplying this g to the code results in the `flat_metric`. (I have pasted my source code here : [Riemann](http://pastebin.com/J7geqQJs), [find_metric](http://pastebin.com/08ygtCcg)).

Note that for a sphere, the metric tensor is defined as

```
g = Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,r**2,0],[0,0,r**2*sin(theta)**2]]).
```

Using this last tensor, my code would then generate the following curve element

```
metric_sphere = TensorProduct(dr, dr) + r**2*sin(theta)**2*TensorProduct(dphi, dphi) + r**2*TensorProduct(dtheta, dtheta)
```

My code takes the metric g,

```
g = Matrix([[0,0,0],[0,r**2,0],[0,0,r**2*sin(theta)**2]]).
```

and determines the curve element (listed above in two-form; `flat_metric`). Note that the metric `g` is singular, hence it can not be used to determine the Christoffel symbols. Instead, I force the user in this case, to provide `flat_g` as an additional argument, so as to reset `g` to `flat_g` after I have determined the curve element. So the most obvious answer in not so obvious any more (i.e that I am providing a singular matrix as an argument.)

With the two-form at hand, I can use the Sympy.Diffgeom library to determine Christoffel Symbols of 1st and 2nd kind, Riemann-Christoffel tensor, Ricci tensor, Scalar-Curvature, etc. However, I get some problems when I provide `flat_metric` as argument to any of the following functions : `metric_to_*` (in Sympy.Diffgeom module).

When I attempt to determine the Christoffel Symbol of Second kind I get the following error :

```
ValueError: Matrix det == 0; not invertible.
```

(I have pasted the entire error message [here](http://pastebin.com/jgBswjK3)).

I get "better" results if I simply hand code for this specific case. In which case, the following code attempts to find the Christoffel symbol of second kind :

```
from sympy.diffgeom import Manifold, Patch, CoordSystem
from sympy.diffgeom import TensorProduct, metric_to_Christoffel_2nd
from sympy import sin, Matrix
dim = 2
m = Manifold("M",dim)
patch = Patch("P",m)
flat_sphere = CoordSystem("flat_sphere", patch, ["theta", "phi"])
theta, phi = flat_sphere.coord_functions()
from sympy.abc import r
g = Matrix([[r**2,0],[0,r**2*sin(theta)**2]])
diff_forms = flat_sphere.base_oneforms()
curve = sum([TensorProduct(di, dj)*g[i, j] 
           for i, di in enumerate(diff_forms) 
           for j, dj in enumerate(diff_forms)])
Matrix(metric_to_Christoffel_2nd(curve))
```

Using this curve element (which produces the exactly the same as my implementation does!) I can calculate the Christoffel Symbols, as well as any order Curvature tensor (i.e Riemann, Ricci, Scalar). However, the Christoffel Symbol that is calculated is incorrect. I have discussed this already in a post at [scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21103/numerical-solution-of-geodesic-differential-equations-with-python). The Christoffel symbol of second kind generated from the above code is :

```
Matrix([[(0,                     0), (0, -sin(theta)*cos(theta))],
        [(0, cos(theta)/sin(theta)), (cos(theta)/sin(theta), 0)]])
```

However, as mentioned in the [scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21103/numerical-solution-of-geodesic-differential-equations-with-python) post, the correct Christoffel symbol is

```
Matrix([[(0,       -tan(theta)), (0, 0)],
        [(sin(theta)*cos(theta), 0), (0, 0)]])
```

So even the hand-coded example fails.

Comment: http://www.quantenforum.de/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=619&hilit=christoffel it's a German site, but the code is commented in English

Comment: I have thought many days about posting this question, yet every time I brought forth any courage to do so, I shivered at the thought of managing to minimize the information that I provide (as to not overwhelm the reader). I hope I have at least managed to accomplish this so some degree. Even so, apologies in advance to anyone who has the courage to go through this, and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to be a bit confusing, but maybe you can try a few things.

First of all, *ValueError: Matrix det == 0; not invertible.* means that you need an invertible matrix. Your metric is singular, so it's not a metric and you cannot use that in your algorithms.

It looks to me that you have defined a metric in a 2-dimensional manifold, and you are trying to find an extension of this metric in a 3-dimensional manifold by naively adding a row and a column of zeros to your 2-dim metric. I don't think that's the right procedure.

The metric induced on a submanifold can be found using a proper formula, see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_metric

Finding the metric on a supermanifold (as in your case) isn't a uniquely defined problem, as there are likely many metrics on a 3D manifold that will induce your metric on the 2D manifold. However, you may still try to use that formula and attempt to build a super-metric to use in 3D space.

Comment: The metric I am using is not singular : `g = Matrix([[r**2,0],[0,r**2*sin(theta)**2]])`. It in fact positive definite.

Comment: The induced metric link is useful. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

sympy.diffgeom.metric_to_Christoffel_2nd(expr)
Return the nested list of Christoffel symbols for the given metric.

Comment: Hi Alexander, welcome to SO! It would be great if you could make a bigger effort formatting your answer and providing links to further resources. Also see the [Help: How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Sorry, a person is trying to do something for which there is a special function in the same module sympy.diffgeom. I think he knows where to get the documentation on this module, since he uses it. I gave the name of the function and what it does too. Thank you.